# get a specific values from a txt file delimited by "|"

Tags: java, csv, txt

How can I get a specific value from a txt file delimited by "|" . I am trying to get the values from column 18 and I get then, but I don't get all of them.
If I take out the validation   `if(csvRecord.size() >= csvParser.getRecordNumber())` I get the error **index 18 out of bounds for length 1.**

Anyone already worked with csvParser and can help me?

this is my code:

```
public static List<String> murexMHEU_TradeCash() throws Exception {
        List<String> MHEUList = new ArrayList<String>();    
        String path = Setup.MHEU_TradeCash; 
        
        
         try (  
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                  CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(br, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter('|'));
                 
                 
                ) {
                    //Skip first line   
                    br.readLine();
                    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                        
                        
                        if(csvRecord.size() >= csvParser.getRecordNumber()){
                            
                             // Accessing Values by Column Index
                            String MurexCounterpartyRef =  csvRecord.get(18);
                            MHEUList.add(MurexCounterpartyRef);

                        }
                        
                    }
                }
         catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println("File not found - " + e.getMessage());
         }
        return MHEUList;
    }
```

Comment: don't you think its more of data issue than anything else ? you are trying to access 18th column, but it does not exist in the row that you are working on

Comment: What does `csvRecord.size() >= csvParser.getRecordNumber()` do? First look it looks like you are checking number of columns in current record with the row number. I might be wrong though.